# Positive parameters for Gamma random variables

Tags: statistics

I am sorry for the poor quality of this question: For $\Gamma(\alpha,\beta)$ random variables, why do we assume $\alpha>0$ and $\beta>0$?

Comment: I don't think the integral of the "density" would converge if the parameters aren't positive (but I may be wrong).

Comment: Why are you apologising for a the quality of the question *when you are the one asking it*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The gamma density is the following, for $x>0$

$$f_X(x,a,b)=\frac{b^a}{\Gamma(a)}x^{a-1}e^{-bx}$$

it is easy to prove that its integral cannot converge if $a,b$ are not both positive